# Load logged user data only once per request

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an application with a security layer using Spring Security with jwt.

We have a method to get the user logged in with some database information, instead of getting the UserDetails data offered by spring.

But we have a big problem every time we need to get the data of the logged in user, it always goes in the base with each call to the `getLoggedInUser()` method, and this causes a lot of calls to the database.

I would like to see a way to have the logged in user loaded by request, and having a call to the bank during the life of that request.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior or something better?

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = ofNullable(userRepository.findByEmailAndActiveTrue(email))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Unidentified user!"));
        
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getAccountList());

        return new SystemUser(user, getGroups(user));
    }

    @Transactional
    public UserInfoDTO getLoggedInUser() {

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String email = userDetails.getUsername();
        SystemUser systemUser = (SystemUser) this.loadUserByUsername(email);
        User user = systemUser.getUser();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getAccountList());

        return UserMapper.USER_MAPPER.from(user);
    }

    private UserDetails getPrincipalSecurity() {

        return (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGroups(User user) {

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        return authorities;
    }
```

The behavior occurs whenever I do this for example

```
@Autowired
private final AppUserDetailService userDetailService;


userDetailService.getLoggedInUser().getAccountList();
```

Comment: Likely, you will not want to store all of the user data in the `SecurityContext` (see alternative in the answer below) as this ends up in the session by default. The other approach would be to enable caching with Spring's [`@Cacheable` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable). You can even add that annotation to your `UserDetailsService` (the `loadUserByUsername()` method).

Answer (score 0):

You can store user details post retrieval in ThreadLocal.

```
@Service
public class Service {
    private static final ThreadLocal<UserInfo> userInfo = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public UserInfo getLoggedInUesr() {

        UserInfo user = userInfo.get();

        if(userInfo.get() == null) {
             user = this.repo.getLoggedInUser();
             userInfo.put(user);
        }

        return user;
        
    }

    
}
```

Once you store user details in `ThreadLocal`, it should be available in the request thread Context.

One other way would be to store all user details once via `UserDetailsService` and store those as `Principal` in `SecurityContext` so that this is available for later.